# Input field data call not translated across form select

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, forms

I have a form that is used to input data into my sql database.  It saves properly when you submit the form, however when you "retrieve" the data to put back in the form, it does not save "option" elements.  Does anyone know why that is?

Form Data Sample(That does save but not return option from database on call) :

```
<select value="<?php echo isset($results['fruit']) ? $results['fruit']: ''; ?>" class="form-control" name="data[fruit]" placeholder="Fruit">
                                <option value="Unset">Fruit:</option>
                                <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
                                <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
```

Form Data Sample(That will save and return data)

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($results['data']['fruit']) ? $results['data']['fruit']: ''; ?>"  type="text" class="form-control" name="data[fruit]" id="fruit" placeholder="Fruit">
```

Comment: Do you mean, why isn't a fruit selected in the drop down list?

Comment: @gilly3 So you select a fruit in the drop down list, and you save the data.  It saves correctly into the sql database, but when you call up the data to edit, it goes back to the "default" view, in this case being "Unset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` elements do not have a `value` attribute.  Instead, add a `selected` attribute to the appropriate `<option>` element.  So, you would have to do something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="data[fruit]">
    <option value="Unset">Fruit:</option>
    <option value="Apples" <?= $fruit == 'Apples' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Apples</option>
    <option value="Bananas" <?= $fruit == 'Bananas' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Bananas</option>
</select>
```

---

A couple notes:

1. `<select>` also lacks a `placeholder` attribute.
2. I omitted your `isset()` code, because that it is so verbose and redundant to include for every `<option>`.  To be a little more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you should do something like:

```
$fruit = $results['fruit'] ?? '';
```

Comment: where the heck can I go to get the skills to just "KNOW" these things? Right now I am in a programming stage where I can tear apart code, and for the most part know how it works, I guess I need a definitive guide on php?  Any ideas?  Thanks a lot by the way!